# Remove from First Array if not found in second Array in MVC

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-mvc

I need to remove all values in my first array if they are not found in the second Array.  However, I cannot find a command for it online in C#; although I have found it for other languages.

Here is my first array:

```
string[] EmailList = (from user in db.Users join subscribor in Subscribors on user.UserId equals subscribor orderby user.FirstName select user.EmailAddress).ToArray();
```

and my second array:

```
string[] TechList = (from user in db.Users join tech in techs on user.UserId equals tech select user.EmailAddress).ToArray();
```

and this is the code that I tried:

```
EmailList = EmailList.Intersect(TechList);
```

I did try a few other variants of intersect but nothing works. On this line of code I am getting the following error:

> cannot emplicitly converty type
>   'system.collections.generic.IEnumerable to string[]

Answer (score 3):

Your code

```
EmailList = EmailList.Intersect(TechList);
```

is otherwise fine but the Intersect returns IEnumerable, and your EmailList is of type string[]. You can convert the IEnumerable to string[] like this

```
EmailList = EmailList.Intersect(TechList).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

`EmailList.Intersect(TechList)` doesn't return a `string[]`; it returns a `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`, like it's telling you.  Try adding a `.ToArray()`, like so:

```
EmailList = EmailList.Intersect(TechList).ToArray();
```